# DSE Solr date range query for String date 'yyyymmdd' & integer hour

Tags: string, date, solr, range, datastax

I'm using Datastax Solr version 4.8. I've column with string values of date in `'yyyymmdd'` format and another column with int values of hour. Now the requirement is to fetch all the records say from `yyyymmdd - '20161110'` to `'20161130'` and from hour  `21 to 15`.

Is there any way to get this search using DSE Solr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up adding timestamp column to get the date range query result.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a copy [copy field](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) with that string date as the source and a date field as the destination. Once your string date has been converted into an actual proper date you can query it like a normal date 'AND' the hour into the query. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Bereng. I created copyfield 'datetime' as:  `<field name="datetime" type="TrieDateField" docValues="true" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/>`  & storing `<copyField source="yyyymmdd" dest="datetime"/>`.                                                                                                                      Now when I query for -->`fq=datetime:[2016-11-10T00:00:00Z TO 2016-11-22T00:00:00Z]`, I don't get any record. I tried removing Time part as well.        Any idea? Secondly how the 'AND' hour part should be queried?